# Python: using reuests library for multipart/form-data

Tags: python, python-2.7, multipartform-data, python-requests

I am fairly a noob at this and have been trying to use `requests` modules to `post` a multipart/form-data. To clarify, the exact test case I am trying to use is the one same as in  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1081. i.e. I am trying to do a `post` without a file :

```
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

value1
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d
```

As per the discussion on the thread, I tried [MultiPart form data scheme](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-data-schemes) to do the following:

```
import requests
from requests_data_schemes import multipart_formdata as mfd
post_data = [('mouseAction', 'toggle'), ('zone' ,'10')]
post_data = mfd(post_data)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

req = requests.post(<url>, data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

However, the test server is throwing me an error saying that it cannot detect the boundary of the multipart form data.

I tried providing the boundary in the header too, but apparently its not working.

```
boundary = post_data[2: post_data.find('\r\n')]
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)}
```

Am i missing something simple?

P.S. From a bit of surfing I found a few solutions using base `urllib2` but that would be my last resort as `requests` lets me do a lot things pretty easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah this is a bug I have to address. You're better off at this point doing the following:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.filepost import encode_multipart_formdata

(content, header) = encode_multipart_formdata([('key', 'value')])
r = requests.post(url, data=content, headers={'Content-Type': header})
```

Comment: really thanks a lot.. have been tearing off my hair since yesterday .. works like a charm

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry that library sucks. It was never released because I was expecting I was going to add more to it. The only good API is the one in urllib3 it just needs to be exposed in a better way.

Comment: Hi, is this still treated as a bug or is there a better way of achieving this from high level api itself ?

Comment: The better way to handle this is by using the requests-toolbelt. This is not a bug nor something Requests is going to change.